# Wget shows connected and then returns 401

Tags: linux, bash, https, wget

I am trying to download a file from my own server using the following command

```
wget --user=test@test.com --password=password123 -nH "http://global.mydommain.com/01-26.zip"
```

I am getting below error

```
Resolving global.mydommain.com... 104.27.150.129, 104.27.151.129, 2606:4700:3034::681b:9781, ...
Connecting to global.mydommain.com|104.27.150.129|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 301 Moved Permanently
Location: https://global.mydommain.com/01-26.zip [following]
--2020-02-02 22:08:12--  https://global.mydommain.com/01-26.zip
Connecting to global.mydommain.com|104.27.150.129|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 401 Unauthorized
Authorization failed.
```

It shows connected, but then 401 Unauthorized...

When I try in a browser it works propery ... any clue what I have done wrong?

PS: I tried  --ask-password but it returned `wget: missing URL`

Comment: Replace `password123` with `'password123'`?

Comment: Is your server behind a security service like Cloudflare or Symantec's Cloud App Security? Is it hosted by a 3rd-party who may be using such a service or implementing their own?

Many of those security services can be problematic when working with wget because they use UA strings, cookies or other techniques to try to block bots, DDoS attacks, etc.